# How to check for duplicated addresses in tables KNA1 and KNB1?

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I need to check if there are duplicated records in the address tables.

The customers are stored in the following tables:

`KNA1` Master data with address, global view

`KNB1` Master data for company code

We were filling into the field `KNB1-ALTKN` the previous number.

Now the idea is to find all duplicated records with this number, but there are only duplicated records if the `KUNNR` is different. Because the same customer can be in several company codes (`BUKRS`), there are for sure more than one entry with the same `ALTKN`.

So the condition here is: different `KUNNR` with the same `ALTKN` means duplicated record.

Can someone please help me do this?

Comment: To clarify the condition: different KUNNR with the same ALTKN and same BUKRS means duplicated record.  If there are different KUNNR, different BUKRS, and same ALTKN, then the foreign key is doing its job, that is, to consolodate & manage customer names & addresses across company codes.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but there's a vastly easier solution for this, that can be expressed with a single pure SQL query... assuming it works ( seeing as some SQL features fail in ABAP Open SQL)...

Anyways, to get your filter criteria, all you need to do is group by the keys you use for finding duplicates (in this case `ALTKN`, `BUKRS`)  and only take groups that have `count ( * )` (record count in a group) higher than 1.

Next use your filter criteria to get the actual results you need.

Here's a full query that solves the problem in this particular case:

```
Select kunnr from kna1 as outer_kna1
where exists (
   "what you select here doesn't matter
   Select 1 from kna1 inner join knb1 on kna1~kunnr = knb1~kunnr 
   where kna1~kunnr = outer_kna1~kunnr
   group by ALTKN, BUKRS "Keys, by which duplicates are searched for
   having count( * ) > 1 "Condition to only select duplicates (in this case, record count in a group is more than 1)
)
into table @lt_duplicate_account_data.
```

`lt_kunnrs_of_duplicate_accounts` will contain customer `kunnrs`, but if you also need `ALTKN` and `BUKRS` too, just add a join in the primary query and add corresponding conditions in the sub-query.

```
Select kunnr, altkn, bukrs from kna1 as outer_kna1 
   inner join outer_knb1 on outer_kna1~kunnr = outer_knb1~kunnr "added join
   where exists (
      "what you select here doesn't matter
      Select kna1~kunnr from kna1 inner join knb1 on kna1~kunnr = knb1~kunnr 
      where kna1~kunnr = outer_kna1~kunnr
      and altkn = outer_knb1~altkn and bukrs = outer_knb1~bukrs "added conditions
      group by ALTKN, BUKRS "Keys, by which duplicates are searched for
      having count( * ) > 1 "Condition to only select duplicates (in this case, record count in a group is more than 1)
   )
into table @lt_duplicate_account_data.
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, in this case You should create an selection Screen, which can take selection options for BUKRS as selection parameter.

And You need a type like types begion of tty_mytype .
                                  kunnr type kunnr,
                                  kunnr2 type kunnr,
                                  altkn type altkn.
                                end of  tty_mytype.

Then You can use a full table scan on KNA1 into hashed table type hashed table of tty_my type.

Join over all tables into the hashed table using a entire table scan, just select KUNNR from KNA1 and ALTKN from KNB1. Thats it.
Use a outer join.

And then You will have to sort the results, best thing, by ALTKN and KUNNR, i think.
And then You need another buffer table, same type.
You must loop over the first hashed table and "collect" all those fitting kunnrs, which have the same ALTKN into the buffer table.
The second buffer table whith the second KUNNR field can hold FIRST KUNNR with ALTKN and the second kunnr field can hold the actual one, which is looped over, where current KUNNR ne "former kunnr" BUT ALTKN eq "former ALTKN".

During loop You can always compare actual KUNNR/ALTKN agains last one.
Do not forget to check for first loop and last one.

Was this helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

Finding all duplicate records would be accomplished by this code.  It looks up all ALTKN for a company code and checks for duplicates:

```
DATA: BEGIN OF duplicate,
  kunnr TYPE knb1-kunnr,
  bukrs TYPE knb1-bukrs,
  altkn TYPE knb1-altkn,
END OF duplicate.
DATA: duplicates LIKE TABLE OF duplicate.

DATA: BEGIN OF altkn_rec,
  altkn TYPE knb1-altkn,
  kunnr TYPE knb1-kunnr,
  bukrs TYPE knb1-bukrs,
END OF altkn_rec.
DATA: altkn_recs LIKE TABLE OF altkn_rec.

DATA: g_bukrs TYPE bukrs,
      previous_record_line TYPE i,
      o_alv TYPE REF TO cl_salv_table.

SELECT bukrs FROM t001 INTO g_bukrs.

  "Get all reference numbers for company code
  SELECT altkn kunnr bukrs
    FROM knb1
    INTO TABLE altkn_recs
    WHERE bukrs = g_bukrs
    ORDER BY altkn.

  "loop over all customer reference numbers, look for duplicates
  LOOP AT altkn_recs INTO altkn_rec.
    AT NEW altkn.
      "Check if more than one line has been read since last record.
      IF ( sy-tabix - previous_record_line ) > 1.
        "Duplicate Found
        READ TABLE altkn_recs INDEX previous_record_line
          INTO altkn_rec.
        MOVE-CORRESPONDING altkn_rec TO duplicate.
        APPEND duplicate TO duplicates.
      ENDIF.

      previous_record_line = sy-tabix.
    ENDAT.
  ENDLOOP.

ENDSELECT.

IF duplicates IS NOT INITIAL.
  cl_salv_table=>factory( IMPORTING r_salv_table = o_alv
                          CHANGING  t_table      = duplicates ).
  o_alv->display( ).
ELSE.
  WRITE 'No Duplicates Found'.
ENDIF.
```